# Share local host with my team members

Tags: xampp, localhost, wamp, sharing, file-sharing

I am developing a website in my local host computer and have files on my computer. My team members want to view the progress of my website through localhost.

That is I want to share local host to my team members to see the progress. They must be able to visit the website which I am developing on their localhost from their own computer. We all are on connected on home network and we have no idea on how share local host with each other.

I need to share my local host on my computer so that he will be able access my local host through his computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box WAMPServer is configured, for your protection, to only allow access from the PC running Apache.

So to allow others to access Apache, all you have to do is tell Apache that it can accept connections from anyone on your internal network. Remember Apache is a web server so you dont need any extra stuff.

If your internal network is secure i.e. is not accessible from the internet **and never will be** all you need to do is, using the wampmanager menus.

```
wampmanager -> Put Online
```

Then tell you co-workers your IP address and they can access your site using your IP address.

If you want to be a little more secure about it, you can do in manually instead by :-

Edit httpd.conf ( using wampmanager menus ) and find this section of that file, and add one line to add access from your local network

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
 ...

 ...

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
# add this line
    Require ip 192.168.1
```

This assumes you are on a subnet starting with `192.168.1`

To check your subnet use this command from a command window

```
ipconfig
```

and look for this line

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.11
```

And then just use the first 3 of the 4 quartiles.

If you only want one or 2 people to see the site you can be more specific and just add their specific ip addresses like this

```
Require ip 192.168.1.20 192.168.1.21
```

Of course this does assume that you PC has a static ip address ( not allocated by DHCP ) and that your wo-workers also have static ip address's. If you dont, this becomes less reliable. If they dont you will have to keep changing the allowed ip addresses every time your Boss/coworkers login.

Comment: And for Xamp how to do this ?

Comment: The same idea, just edit httpd.conf manually, find the section in httpd.conf that controls the htdocs folder and add the privilege statement(s) in the same way. XAMPP is apache just like WAMPServer. Sorry I missed that you were using XAMPP